# Is there a fast language that supports portable continuations?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, continuations

I'm looking for a fast language (ie. a language that can be compiled natively to achieve performance not more than 3 or 4 times slower than C), which supports portable continuations.  By this I mean a continuation that can be serialized on one computer, and deserialized on another.

I know that SISC can do this (a Scheme implementation in Java), but its slow.  Ditto for Rhino (a Javascript implementation in Java).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scala 2.8.0 will allow continuations, and they'll be portable.

Answer (score 8):

Did you checked **OCaml** ? It can be compiled and should be marginally slower than C.

[Continuations and delimited control](http://okmij.org/ftp/Computation/Continuations.html)

Answer (score 6):

While I agree that dialects of Caml might be an excellent choice I feel I have to mention [Gambit Scheme](https://github.com/mindpool/gambit-termite). Together with Termite, an erlang-like framework it has support for serializing continuations, sending them over the wire, and much more.

It compiles to C-code.

Answer (score 2):

Its possible to do serializable continuations in Java using Apache JavaFlow - if you do go that route then the Swing Continuations library at:

http://www.exploringexcellence.com/swingcontinuations/download.html

makes it the coding a lot more pleasant.

Comment: Looks like the project moved. Here is the original author's last related blog entry (http://blog.araneaframework.org/2007/06/11/aranea-and-swing-get-continuations) and the jar file is available in the downloads section for the Arenea Framework project on sourceforge (http://sourceforge.net/projects/araneaframework/files)